# Beginner cannot access python's imrotate

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I Googled "python rotate image" and it sent me to scipy.misc.imrotate. I then imported scipy and scipy.misc

```
import scipy.misc as misc
```

failed. I don't know why, but it worked when I didn't try renaming.
help('scipy.misc') lists imrotate as an available function, but said that "pillow" is needed. So I went back into the Macos Unix shell and typed

```
pip3 install pillow
```

which worked. but I still get an error from python3

```
scipy.misc.imrotate
>>> scipy.misc.imrotate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imrotate'
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imrotate.html) says that it is deprecated and will be removed in scipy 1.2.

Comment: If you use the import statement `import scipy.misc as misc`, then you must use `misc.imrotate` (not `scipy.misc.imrotate`) to access the `imrotate` function.

Comment: @MrT What exactly is deprecated.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Thanks. I tried what you suggest and then typed misc.imrotate. This gave an error message          
AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imrotate'

Comment: @DavidEpstein It will not be supported in the future. So if you write a script today and only want to use it in the next two weeks, you don't have to care about it. But if you expect this script to work in three years time, it is better to use the suggested alternative.

Comment: @MrT https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imrotate.htm is helpful. The site recommends skimage.transform.rotate. The deprecated function gives a choice of interpolation algorithm. The replacement function gives no choice. II want to use bicubic interpolation by convolution. The rotate function will then be continuously differentiable function of angle and matrix entries (except at image centre) (but it will be slower). Should I ask another question? Is this the best forum for such a question?

Answer (score 0):

imrotate is deprecated! imrotate is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and is removed in 1.2.0. 
You can use skimage.transform.rotate instead.